# Was bedeutet "die innseitige Wand" in diesem Zusammenhang

Tags: adjective, compound-adjective

Ich habe eine Situation, in der es drei parallele Wände gibt. Hier ist eine schematische Skizze zu dieser Situation:

[image]

Was bedeutet in diesem Zusammenhang "die innseitige Wand"? Was ist überhaupt "innseitig" und was ist "innenseitig" und was ist der Unterschied zwischen "innseitig" und "innenseitig"?

Ich vermute, dass es beim Ausdruck "die innseitige Wand" die mittlere Wand gemeint ist, aber kann man das auch mit der Sprache begründen?!

Danke für eure Hilfe im Voraus!

Comment: Nein. Das kann man nicht begründen und wie kommst du darauf?

Comment: Zunächst einmal ist die Schreibung "innseitig" unglücklich. Entweder sollte es *innenseitig* sein oder *inseitig* (wie inwendig, inwärts, etc.). Auf die Bedeutung hat das natürlich keinen Einfluss.

Comment: Eine inhaltliche Antwort ist - nur gestützt auf Text und Zeichnung - nicht möglich. Dazu ist der sprachliche Ausdruck viel zu unpräzise. Man bräuchte den gesamten Kontext. Was soll mit oder an dieser Wand gemacht werden? Soll sie abgerissen werden? Soll ein Bild dran aufgehängt werden? Was ist zwischen diesen Wänden? Betretbare Räume? Oder ungenutzter (ggf. wäremisolierender) Luftraum? - Merke auch: Es liegt nicht an Dir, dass du das nicht verstehst. Der Ausdruck ist einfach uneindeutig.

Comment: Ist das eventuell in Innsbruck oder Salzburg?

Comment: Willkommen auf German SE! Vielleicht wurde da jemand vom englischen *inside* beeinflusst? Von innerer, mittlerer und äußerer Wand zu sprechen wäre hier in der Tat sinnvoller, da eine Wand zwei Seiten hat, die nicht beide "inn(en)seitig" sein können. Für eine belastbare Antwort fehlt somit der Kontext, jedoch hilft eventuell der Hinweis, dass ich darunter die Wand ganz rechts verstehen würde, da *innseitig* (vielleicht war auch *innenliegend* gemeint?) bei einem Haus wohl das Gegenteil der Außenseite wäre.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass das Wort in einem Angebot eines Handwerksbetriebs vorkommt. Falls ich Recht habe, solltest Du den Kontext etwas näher darstellen. Und nicht durch Kommentare irritieren lassen ...

Comment: Der [DWDS Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=innseitig) hat zwar zwei Treffer, aber es geht auch nicht mehr daraus hervor, als dass es irgendwie auf der Innenseite ist, im Prinzip kann man auch die Innenseite der Außenwand nicht ausschließen.

Comment: Weiter trägt zur Konfusion bei, dass *Wand* zwei Dinge bedeuten kann: 1) eine Mauer - also ein physisches Objekt (Gebäudeteil) das zwei vertikale Flächen hat, und dazwischen ein Volumen. 2) Genau eine von diesen zwei Seiten: Wenn man zum Beispiel im Zimmer sitzt und die "Wand" anschaut. Dann meint man nur diese "Sichtseite" (die volumenlos ist). - Entsprechend kann eine "innenliegende Wand" sich auf eine "innere Mauer" beziehen (z.B. bei einem Haus mit Klinkerfassade), oder es kann die "von innen sichtbare Wanfläche" gemeint sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Bedeutung von *Wand*

Zunächst einmal ist zu unterscheiden zwischen *Wand* im Sinne von *Seite* oder *Fläche* und *Wand* im Sinne von *Mauer*. Beispielsweise findet man in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wand) folgende Definitionen:

> **Bedeutungen:**
>
> [1] Seite oder Fläche, die irgendeinen Raum oder Hohlkörper begrenzt
>
> …
>
> [3] Architektur: ein senkrecht stehendes Bauteil, das einen Raum seitlich begrenzt, besonders die nach innen gewandte Fläche dieses Bauteils
>
> **Synonyme:**
>
> [1] Wandung
>
> [3] Mauer

#### Mauerwände in der Skizze

In der schematischen Skizze werden Wände im Sinne von Mauern gezeigt. Allerdings sind die Beschriftungen meines Erachtens nicht richtig. Wenn ich die Skizze richtig interpretiere und annehme, dass der ganz rechts neben allen Strichen befindliche Weißbereich den Innenraum darstellt, dann sehe ich

- links in Schwarz eine [*Außenwand*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Au%C3%9Fenwand) oder Außenmauer,
- rechts in Schwarz eine [*Innenwand*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Innenwand) oder Innenmauer
- und in der Mitte in Rot eine *Zwischenwand* oder Zwischenmauer.

(Ob *Zwischenwand* hier tatsächlich der fachlich korrekte Begriff ist, weiß ich nicht. Laut Wiktionary verbindet man mit [*Zwischenwand*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwischenwand) offenbar eher eine zusätzliche, nichttragende Wand im Innenraum, zu der ich wiederum *Trennwand* sagen würde.)

#### Außen-, innen- und innseitige Flächenwände

Die Adjektive *außenseitig* und *innenseitig* ergeben nur bei Wänden im Sinne von *Flächen* Sinn. Die innenseitige Wand wäre dann diejenige, die den Innenraum auskleidet.

*Innseitig* scheint eine Variante von *innenseitig* zu sein. Das DWDS listet Korpusbelege für beide Varianten auf ([hier](https://www.dwds.de/r/?from=&h=1&corpus=kern&q=innseitig) und [hier](https://www.dwds.de/r/?from=&h=1&corpus=kern&q=innenseitig)), wenn auch nicht viele. In den Wörterbüchern des DWDS ist keines der Adjektive verzeichnet.

Comment: Vgl. auch engl. *inside* (mögliche Wechselwirkung).

Comment: Gute  Antwort (+1). Aber einer Erklärung von "Wand" hätte es nicht bedurft ;-)

Comment: "Die innenseitige Wand wäre dann diejenige, die den Innenraum auskleidet"

Wieso kannst nicht einfach schreiben: Der dritte schwarze Strich von links oder der erste schwarze Strich von rechts?

Comment: @AhmedHossam, weil der zitierte Satz sich gar nicht auf die Skizze mit den Mauerwänden bezieht, sondern ganz allgemein auf beliebige Flächenwände, die man mit den entsprechenden Adjektiven charakterisieren kann. (Siehe auch die verschiedenen Überschriften.)